# How to configure scidb to use ChessBase files like ChessBase?

Tags: software, chessbase, scidb

I've just installed [scidb](http://scidb.sourceforge.net), hoping that it would read my ChessBase Fritz Trainer collection.
It was able to read the .CBH files but no video appears. I don't know if that is even supported.
If it is, how can I use it ? If it isn't, how can I mimic this behavior ?

Comment: Wow that's surprising scidb can read cbh files. I thought all chessbase database software was proprietary to stop people ripping them off. I'd be very surprised if you could get video working.

Comment: @magd: Well, all chessbase database software are proprietary. scidb's developer just kept tinkering with deciphering methods until he found it, I guess. Because that would be the *only* way to do so. I am trying to get video working. Wish me luck!

Comment: good luck! Let us know if you manage it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scidb does not support videos, and I don't think that videos will be supported before the second alpha version is released. Currently Scidb is still a beta (test) version. Whether it is really possible to read the ChessBase videos - this includes also the associated timing data - is still an open question.

Comment: You're going to find it hard to decode their video stuffs. Forget it and release. It was beta 4 years ago and it's still beta. The project is heading like ReactOS.